# CryptDeriveKey fails for AES algorithm name

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to implement AES encryption in my application. I have the following code to create a hashed version of the user password.

```
PasswordDeriveBytes passwdHash = new PasswordDeriveBytes( password, salt, 
                                                          "SHA1", 128 );
byte[] keyBytes                = passwdHash.CryptDeriveKey( "AES", "SHA1", 
                                                            192, iv );
```

The second line throws a `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException` with the error message `Object identifier (OID) is unknown`. I used Reflector to verify that the error is being thrown because `CryptDeriveKey()` does not like the "AES" algorithm name (I'm using `AesCryptoServiceProvider()` to perform the encryption). I tried changing the name to "AESManaged", "AES192" and "Rijndael" but they all throw the same exception.

How do I get this to work? Or is there an alternative method of deriving the key bytes?
Also, is there any documentation on what the allowed algorithm name strings are? I can't find anything on the MSDN docs for that function.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and target .NET framework 3.5

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you want to derive a key from a password salt rather than the password itself? Usually you use the "raw" password and a salt; indeed in my book (*grin*) chapter 6 has the following sample.

```
private void GetKeyAndIVFromPasswordAndSalt(
    string password, 
    byte[] salt, 
    SymmetricAlgorithm symmetricAlgorithm, 
    ref byte[] key, 
    ref byte[] iv)
{
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898DeriveBytes = 
        new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt);
    key = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(symmetricAlgorithm.KeySize / 8);
    iv =  rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(symmetricAlgorithm.BlockSize / 8); 
}
```

Of course salt should be a cryptographically secure random byte array;

```
private static byte[] GenerateKeyGenerateRandomBytes(int length)
{
    byte[] key = new byte[length];
    RNGCryptoServiceProvider provider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    provider.GetBytes(key);
    return key;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, I am deriving the hash from the raw password (first parameter to the `PasswordDeriveBytes` constructor) and a random salt (generated exactly the way you posted). I'm far from a crypto expert, so it is very much possible I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: OK well, deriving from a hash seems to me to be wrong - that implies that you're storing the password hash somewhere, which is the main reason of hashing. If you're storing the hash, well then anyone can derive the keys as they know the starting point. If you were doing that you may as well just choose a random key.

Comment: Hmm, my plan is to do this: user provides password, I generate a random salt and use salt + password to generate hash. This hash will be used to encrypt a file and salt is stored along with the file (unencrypted) (I read somewhere that storing salt is OK). For decryption user provides password, I use that and salt to generate hash again and try to decrypt the file using the hash.

Comment: Ah it's the variable name that threw me, you're not deriving a hash, you're creating a key derived from the password :) My code just uses another key algorithm, albeit one only suitable for symmetric encryption, which looks like what you'd be using anyway.

Comment: I blame the person who posted this code on his blog, he called it a hash :-D

Comment: So can I use the IV and salt generated from `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` as shown in your example with `AesCryptoServiceProvider` (or `AESManaged`)?

Comment: See that's why you shouldn't read blogs, you should buy my book instead *duck/hide*

Comment: And yes, you can plug the key and IV into any of the symmetric algorithms. Indeed it'll adjust the key and IV size according to the algorithm instance you pass in.

Comment: **Q:** *Why do you want to derive a key from a password salt rather than the password itself?* **A:** Because `CryptDeriveKey` uses the **standard** **[PBKDF1 algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)** which makes it harder to do a brute force attack because there are cycles implemented to slow down the generation process (you can increase the cycles to adapt to current CPU's performance). So if you try out the password you must go through this method and it takes significantly longer for an attacker. Also, the algorithm uses the keyspace in an optimal way by adding entropy.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this doesn't support AES: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/61d85001-2eae-4419-b4bf-ce98d46f4d21/

I also found this: http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidDDE5F3FF54C91BC673350363EAECC0D815A68F92.aspx

It looks like Rijndael should work. It appears that the key size is only set to 16 though...

Comment: I'd found the second link too but it doesn't work, same exception is thrown.