# CryptDeriveKey algorithm names

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes, password-encryption

```
public byte[] CryptDeriveKey(
    string algname,
    string alghashname,
    int keySize,
    byte[] rgbIV
)
```

Can someone please enlighten me as to what options there are in algname? If I want to specify an encryption algorithm for AES-128 and AES-256, what should I put in the algname?

Comment: You should use [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx). This uses a safer, more up to date key derivation method: PBKDF2 instead of PBKDF1. The implementation of `PasswordDeriveBytes` is horribly broken, especially for output over 20 bytes, in which case it is not just broken but unsafe as well.

Comment: Implementing cryptography is hard, I've ported Google's [Keyczar](http://keyczar.org) framework to [.net](http://jbtule.github.com/keyczar-dotnet/) for that reason. Primitives to encrypt with AES are not designed to be straight forward for correct usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but, `algname` is your algorithm name. `keySize` is size of the key.

You should use `AES-128` and `AES-256` like this;

```
CryptDeriveKey("AES", "SHA1", 128, aes.IV)
```

and

```
CryptDeriveKey("AES", "SHA1", 256, aes.IV)
```

Check out for more details from *[`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.passwordderivebytes.cryptderivekey.aspx)*.

Here is a decompiled code for `PasswordDeriveBytes.CryptDeriveKey` method.

```
[SecuritySafeCritical]
public byte[] CryptDeriveKey(string algname, string alghashname, int keySize, byte[] rgbIV)
{
    if (keySize < 0)
    {
        throw new CryptographicException(Environment.GetResourceString("Cryptography_InvalidKeySize"));
    }
    int algidHash = X509Utils.NameOrOidToAlgId(alghashname, OidGroup.HashAlgorithm);
    if (algidHash == 0)
    {
        throw new CryptographicException(Environment.GetResourceString("Cryptography_PasswordDerivedBytes_InvalidAlgorithm"));
    }
    int algid = X509Utils.NameOrOidToAlgId(algname, OidGroup.AllGroups);
    if (algid == 0)
    {
        throw new CryptographicException(Environment.GetResourceString("Cryptography_PasswordDerivedBytes_InvalidAlgorithm"));
    }
    if (rgbIV == null)
    {
        throw new CryptographicException(Environment.GetResourceString("Cryptography_PasswordDerivedBytes_InvalidIV"));
    }
    byte[] o = null;
    DeriveKey(this.ProvHandle, algid, algidHash, this._password, this._password.Length, keySize << 0x10, rgbIV, rgbIV.Length, JitHelpers.GetObjectHandleOnStack<byte[]>(ref o));
    return o;
}
```

Here is a decompiled code of `NameOrOidToAlgId` method.

```
internal static int NameOrOidToAlgId(string oid, OidGroup oidGroup)
{
    if (oid == null)
    {
        return 0x8004;
    }
    string str = CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID(oid, oidGroup);
    if (str == null)
    {
        str = oid;
    }
    int algIdFromOid = GetAlgIdFromOid(str, oidGroup);
    switch (algIdFromOid)
    {
        case 0:
        case -1:
            throw new CryptographicException(Environment.GetResourceString("Cryptography_InvalidOID"));
    }
    return algIdFromOid;
}
```

Comment: OK THANKS, is there any way you can find out the method NameOrOidtoAlgId - what values it takes?

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. Unfortunately it seems that it does not support AES. I have no idea what alternative method to use.

Comment: @michelle Check this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384035/cryptderivekey-fails-for-aes-algorithm-name

Comment: No - `taes.Key = pdb.CryptDeriveKey("AES", "SHA1", 256, taes.IV);` does not work for me. It throws the exception "Object identifier (OID) is unknown". But AES is an important algorithm. The MSDN link provided only tells about the anclient "TripleDES", but does not reveal what to use for "AES". And "AES-256" is also not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have here a dissasembler like `Reflector` to find the solution. If you have one go to `mscorlib.dll` and decompile `PasswordDerivedBytes.CryptDeriveKey` method. You will find there the  supported strings.

By the way, AES is not supported: [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/61d85001-2eae-4419-b4bf-ce98d46f4d21/)

Answer (score 0):

One can use TripleDES for algname parameter.

Ex:

```
TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("password", 24, 1000);
byte[] key = pdb.CryptDeriveKey("TripleDES", "SHA256", 192, tdes.IV);
```

Click here to see documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.passwordderivebytes.cryptderivekey?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Security_Cryptography_PasswordDeriveBytes_CryptDeriveKey_System_String_System_String_System_Int32_System_Byte___)